# Should dummy variables be normalized along with numeric variables when doing kmeans clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means, centering

I am trying to cluster the data set 'How Americans spend their time' using kmeans clustering.

The data set contains education, gender and age-range (55-60, 60-65 etc) as categorical variables and rest of the variables such as no-of-hours in socializing & relaxing, no-of-hours shopping, no-of-hours watching TV etc are all integers.

I have converted categorical variables to dummy variables. Next step is scaling (scaling and centering). Should I center and scale dummy variables also along with numeric variables.

I get very different clusters when I center and scale dummy variables (along with numeric variables) than when I center and scale numeric variables only. Which approach should I rely on? My feeling is I should also center and scale dummy variables along with numeric variables.

Comment: K-means is not recommended with binary data. And for dummy variables - simply inappropriate. http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/174556/3277; http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81549/3277; http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148417/3277.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140711 for how standardization changes clusters.